# How to set selections Angular mat-selection-list using object from another component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component I made using mat-selection-list for a checkbox list. When I was using an array of strings it worked great. I've since had to update it to use an array of object so I can pass ids back to the api instead of values. Now my component doesn't pre-select options that I'm passing to it.
Here's my slackblitz  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-yghjci
Component HTML

```
<mat-selection-list #optionList [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
            <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before" *ngFor="let optionItem of listOfOptions" [value]="optionItem">
                {{optionItem.optionName | titlecase}}
            </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
```

Using Component

```
<app-checkbox-list [listOfOptions]="myOptionList" [(selectedOptions)]="mySelectedOptions"></app-checkbox-list>
```

Initializing Data

```
myOptionList:Array<ICheckBoxListOption>;
mySelectedOptions: Array<ICheckBoxListOption>;

listOfOptionsFromAPI: Array<ICheckBoxListOption> = [
  {optionId: "001", optionName: "test1"},
  {optionId: "002", optionName: "test2"},
  {optionId: "003", optionName: "test3"},
  {optionId: "004", optionName: "test4"},
  {optionId: "005", optionName: "test5"},
];

preSelectedOptionsFromAPI: Array<ICheckBoxListOption> = [
 {optionId: "003", optionName: "test3"},
  {optionId: "005", optionName: "test5"},
];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myOptionList = this.listOfOptionsFromAPI;
  this.mySelectedOptions = this.preSelectedOptionsFromAPI;
}
```

Comment: You should provide a minimal example in your question, not only as a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I manged to fix my issue by reworking how the objects were being assigned.

I changed

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myOptionList = this.listOfOptionsFromAPI;
    this.mySelectedOptions = this.preSelectedOptionsFromAPI;
}
```

To

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myOptionList = this.listOfOptionsFromAPI;
    this.mySelectedOptions = this.listOfOptionsFromAPI.filter(option => { return this.preSelectedOptionsFromAPI.find(select => {return option.optionId == select.optionId})});
}
```

This seems to allow the objects to be truely equal instead of the values being equal.

Slackblitz Solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-in9ub6

Answer (score 0):

Update your `preSelectedOptionsFromAPI` to:

```
  preSelectedOptionsFromAPI: Array<ICheckBoxListOption> = [
    this.listOfOptionsFromAPI[2],
    this.listOfOptionsFromAPI[4]
  ];
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-mdo6fm?file=app/app.component.ts)**

**Update**:

If pre-selected options coming from different api then, just find out index of those objects in initial `listOfOptionsFromAPI` array.

```
let option1FromAPI = {optionId: "003", optionName: "test3"};
let option2FromAPI = {optionId: "005", optionName: "test5"};
let option1Index = this.listOfOptionsFromAPI.findIndex(x => x.optionId === option1FromAPI.optionId);
let option2Index = this.listOfOptionsFromAPI.findIndex(x => x.optionId === option2FromAPI.optionId);
this.preSelectedOptionsFromAPI = [this.listOfOptionsFromAPI[option1Index], this.listOfOptionsFromAPI[option2Index]];
```

[**Stackblitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-85zx2a?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This doesn't help in the long run as those 2 variable would be coming from API endpoints (separate endponts at that). It is interesting that, that fixes the issue. Do I have an object equality problem?

Comment: @J.Sexton Yeah you've object equality problem. If those options coming from different api end points then you've to filter it using array.findindex & ultimately have to give indexes of those options you're showing

Comment: Thanks for the updated. This helps a lot. I totally didn't think about the objects not be considered equal even if their values are completely the same.